# UItextView get Magnifier position as it moves on the screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextview

I have a UITextView which does not contain any text in it. When I long press on this view, the magnifier comes up on the screen and I can moved my finger around with the magnifier. Question is: As I am moving the magnifier, is there any way to trap this finger movements to get the magnifier position?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with touch methods.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   NSLog(@"****touchesEnded");
   [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event];  
   NSLog(@"****touchesEnded");
   [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
   NSLog(@"****touchesEnded");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touches... etc]; 
    NSLog(@"touchesCancelled");
}
```

Comment: I did try this earlier. Forgot to mention it. This doesnt work when the magnifier is on the screen. TouchesMoved doesnt get called while moving the magnifier.